# Rabin Karp for multiple Pattern different length

Tags: algorithm, search, pattern-matching, search-engine, rabin-karp

I know Rabin Karp is faster for multiple Pattern but it should be same length.
But now i have 10 Pattern different length and need to search in text.
How it work effective ?
Thanks!